# Jekyll + gh-pages + GoDaddy blog doesn't seem to load properly on Macs

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I've recently created a blog using Jekyll and Github Pages and bought a custom domain from GoDaddy. While it seems to work fine on my windows laptop, my phone, and my friend's computers, most of the times that I try to load it on my MacBook Pro it goes to one of the following pages:

- Custom GoDaddy page with ads.
- What seems to be a GoDaddy page with message: "website coming soon! Please check back soon to see if the site is available."
- Github Pages message: "404: File not found The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL. For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file."

I also noticed that sometimes the page fails to open and redirects to the url with a /xxxx/ in the end like http://page.com/KQMRn/.

In case it helps, the page is joelcponte.com and the GitHub repository is GitHub.com/joelcponte/blog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DNS configuration seems to be wrong :

```
dig joelcponte.com

;; ANSWER SECTION:
joelcponte.com.     238 IN  A   184.168.221.38
joelcponte.com.     238 IN  A   192.30.252.153
joelcponte.com.     238 IN  A   192.30.252.154
```

You must remove the first DNS (184.168.221.38) which is a GoDaddy IP.