# TLS certificate is being provisioned. This may take up to 15 minutes to complete

Tags: certificate, github-pages, tls1.2

[image]

I see this message when trying to enforce https on my github pages website with a custom domain, which I registered through GoDaddy. The message showed up when I first linked my custom domain, but it's still there a week later.

Other Context:

- I added A records on GoDaddy pointing to the github pages IP addresses.
- When I attempt to access my website on mobile, it says that the website is being parked by GoDaddy.

What might be preventing the certificate from going through?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://github.community/t/certificate-request-error-is-persistent-tls-certificate-cant-be-provisioned/11008/12). The problem was that I hadn't deleted the A record that GoDaddy automatically includes, parking your website. I deleted this A record and the certificate went through within a few minutes.

[image]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648486/jekyll-gh-pages-godaddy-blog-doesnt-seem-to-load-properly-on-macs) describes a different problem with the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is specific for cloudflare, I got to disable proxy through cloudflare servers and only use DNS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update for those in a similar situation. Adding a www CNAME record fixed the error following the advice from [this post](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/22052). My DNS custom resource records section now looks like this:

[image]

You can trigger the TLS certificate process by temporarily removing your custom domain and adding it again. A couple of minutes later I was able to check the “Enforce HTTPS” check box again.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable Cloudflare proxy service for this TLS feature.

[image: Cloudflare DNS Setting]