# Github pages not provisioning TLS certificate. "TLS certificate is being provisioned. This may take up to 15 minutes to complete."

Tags: github, https, github-pages, tls1.2

[image]

I've had this error for over 24 hours now. Unlike this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096356/tls-certificate-is-being-provisioned-this-may-take-up-to-15-minutes-to-complete), I only have the 4 A records and 1 CNAME record, which point to github's 4 addresses and myusername.github.io. There's no parking A record which could be causing the error. I've followed all the instructions outlined from [github](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site) and [namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9645/2208/how-do-i-link-my-domain-to-github-pages/)

[image]

What's preventing github from provisioning my TLS certificate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out it was a glitch from Github. After switching the domain from [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) to domain.com then back to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) twice, the certificate was provisioned.

Comment: This happens to me too. Also be aware not to delete the CNAME file that github drops into your repo

Answer (score 0):

A little color on this. I found that my certificate and custom domain kept resetting.

Github places a CNAME file with the custom domain name in the root of the of the directory being served.

The static site generator I was using kept blowing this file away on every deployment.

So beware!